# how does returning an object work with assignment operator?

Tags: c++

Assume we have the following operation:

```
Object a = b.copy();
```

`copy()` is basically a method which copies an object and returns its copy.

```
Object copy()
{ 
    Object copied_Object;
    /..do the copy../
    return copied_Object;
}
```

At first I thought the return would trigger an assignment `operator =` and place 
the result at the right field of the operation, but it turned out that actually the copy constructor gets activated and then the Object created inside the function gets destroyed. This is what I know.

My question is, can you explain to me step by step what happens when `Object a = b.copy();` is executed?

Comment: 1. `Object a = b.copy();` is not an assignment. 2. Why not `return *this;`? Copy constructor has its name for a reason.

Comment: copy elision can also occur (and will in C++17).

Comment: I'm just asking what happens when it gets compiled, so assignment doesn't get triggered, i guess that make sense since it also doesn't get triggered when i write Object a = b;

Comment: Usually copy assignment and copy construction have deep copy semantics, so there is no need to say `Object a = b.copy()` instead of `Object a = b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object a = b.copy();
```

Is an instruction to create/construct/initialize an Object. No assignment is involved.

Assignments looks like this,

```
object = something;
```

Notice the absence of a declaration of object.

Now

```
Object a = b.copy();
```

constructs a, by a b.copy() of type `Object`, this requires `Object` to have the ability to be constructed by another `Object`. This is of course the copy constructor. Either the compiler generated, or a defaulted, or an explicit copy constructor.

When the statement is executed, the copy function will execute and transfer the created copied_Object to the caller by either

1. Copy construction
2. Copy elision, the compiler will invoke its black-magic box and construct Object `a` in-place. No copy construction necessary. As hinted by Jarod.

As LogicStuff, suggests you can do

```
Object copy()
{ 
    return *this;
}
```

This copies the contents of the `b` object to the return value and requires a copy constructor.

I'll steal Daniel H's comment too and conclude that

```
Object a = b;
```

will carry the exact same semantics under normal circumstances. I.e. circumstances of least surprise.

Comment: @Raeedmndow If an answer satisfies you, you should check the green check-mark next to the answer. This goes for your other questions as well.